# Why isn't there spell checking on the edit summary input?

Tags: support, editor, edit-summary

While reviewing suggested edits I often see this an edit summary similar to this:

> fix grammer

when I first saw it I thought it was an ironically amusing mistake, but now I've seen it so many times that I've started wondering if it's actually some kind of editor inside joke that I'm unaware of. (Sub-question: Is it?)

I wondered why someone who cared enough to edit things and thought they had mastered English well enough to edit other people's "grammer" wouldn't notice that they were misspelling a word. Out of curiosity, I entered it like that myself and noticed it wasn't spellchecked. For other inputs, (e.g. questions, comments) the browser spellcheck works and misspellings are marked, but they aren't in this one.

This is a pretty minor thing; I'm sure a lot of people just get used to ignoring the red underline anyway. I was just curious if anyone knew if this was by design, and if so, what its purpose was.

This happens in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Comment: Good question. Spellcheck doesn't work in the Question title either. Very annoying. It seems to only work in multi-line text fields

Comment: In Chrome 48, I do get spell checking in the edit summary (and in the title). I recall in FF having to turn it on in some fields.

Comment: Ah, I am using Firefox, and I can turn it on manually. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: I'm still not certain why why the other inputs, (comments, etc.) seem to default to spellcheck on in FF. I'm pretty sure I never manually set them before. I wonder if `spellcheck="true"` would be appropriate or useful here.

Comment: You might mention that it is a Firefox issue since it doesn't happen in Chrome.  Including your browser and OS in bug reports is helpful.

Comment: Sadly, it's not a joke. I can't tell you how many edits I've seen where the summary said "improved formatting" while the edit did the exact opposite.

Comment: @Don'tPanic no problem.  It became a lot more obvious once the comments figured it out.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a Firefox setting that you need to enable. By default, Firefox only checks multi-line textboxes.

You can adjust this by following these steps:

- In the URL bar, type `about:config`
- Search for [`Layout.spellcheckDefault`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Layout.spellcheckDefault)
- Change the default value of `1` to `2`

Other options that are available:

> 0 - Disable spellchecker.
>
> 1 - Enable spellchecker for multi-line controls (e.g., `<textarea>`s). (Default in Firefox and SeaMonkey)
>
> 2 - Enable spellchecker for multi-line controls and single-line controls. (Default in Camino)

In Chrome this information is at:

```
Settings\Advanced Settings
```

[image: Accessing Language Settings in Chrome]

And then check the Enable spell checking box

[image: Checkbox for Spellchecker]

Comment: This is not sufficient if a dictionary is not installed. E.g. right click in an edit field and chose "Add Dictionaries..." (if it is already installed there is instead a "Check Spelling" menu item in that context menu).